# Updating a list of lists

Tags: c#, list

I have an application that has several lists to keep track of some values during the running of the application. In particular it has List1, List2 and MainList.

List1 and List2 are of type String and MainList is a list of the 2 other lists.

In my application I wish to update and change the values of the lists as the application is running but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this.

Its a image manipulation application that processes photographs from a file. The application needs to process the values of the lists for all the photos in the file. Therefore it will have a loop that iterates over all the photos and updates the lists with each iteration.

My algorithmic should look as follows:
* If its the first image, add the strings to List1. Then add List1 to MainList
* For each consecutive image, add that images' strings to List2. Then add List2 to MainList. Set List1 as the last List that was added to MainList. Clear List2

Problem is that when I clear List2 data, it also clears the data for List1 to which it has been set. How can I stop this from happening. I've enclosed my code which should hopefully make more sense. In my code I've omitted the checks to see if its the first image as I was just testing the algorithm.

```
List<List<String>> MainStringList = new List<List<String>>();
List<String> StringList1 = new List<String>();
List<String> StringList2 = new List<String>();

StringList1.Add("My Car");
StringList1.Add("My Engine");
StringList1.Add("My Wheel");

MainStringList.Add(StringList1);

StringList2.Add("My Flower");
StringList2.Add("My Honey");
StringList2.Add("My Love Heart");

DoStuff(StringList1, StringList2);

private void DoStuff(List<String> StringList1, List<String> StringList2)
{
    // Perform some calculations 
    // Then add to list
    MainStringList.Add(StringList2);

    int mainStringListCount = MainStringList.Count;

    StringList1 = MainStringList[mainStringListCount - 1];

    String test1 = StringList1[2];

    StringList2.Clear();

    String test2 = StringList1[2];      // Problem is here - clears StringList2 as well as StringList1
}
```

Comment: @Hans Moolman StringList2.Clear(); will not clear StringList1 unless you say StringList1 = StringList2...but I don't see that in your code...

Comment: Oops sorry guys, meant to say I'm doing it in C#. _italic StringList2.Clear(); will not clear StringList1 unless you say StringList1 = StringList2_ As Im adding StringList2 to my MainList and then using that to set my StringList1, it does actually clear it. I have stepped through the code and after StringList2.Clear() my StringList1's values are all null. Unless Im doing something else wrong along the way but I cant see anything that would suggest that I am?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let me step you through it

```
MainStringList.Add(StringList2);
// list count goes up from 1 to 2

int mainStringListCount = MainStringList.Count; 
// Set mainStringListCount = 2

StringList1 = MainStringList[mainStringListCount - 1]; 
// Set StringList1 to the reference at index 1 (2 - 1) of your array
// This sets Stringlist1 to StringList2 since arrays are 0 based.
// StringList1 and StringList2 now both referece the same list.

StringList2.Clear();
// Clears the list that is referecned by both variables
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few problems I've noticed  (would have made this a comment, but it's too complicated without some spacing).

In your DoStuff() method:

```
MainStringList.Add(StringList2);
```

... this adds a **object reference value** to `StringList2` to `MainStringList`.  I hope you understand that.

```
StringList1 = MainStringList[mainStringListCount - 1];
```

... this gets the last value added to `MainStringList` which is what you just added in the first line of code in your `DoStuff` method.

The second to last line in the method is:

```
StringList2.Clear();
```

`StringList1` is a stack reference to the exact same object that `StringList2`'s stack reference is pointing to.  So essentially, you've got one list you're actually working with here, and in the end it's completely empty because you called `Clear()` on the stack reference which is pointing to the one and only `List` heap object.  You need to create new `List` objects instead of working with the same one over and over.

EDIT: Derp, Jodrell beat me.